# Экспорт данных в xml c помощью bcp

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, bcp

Есть БД ms sql 2008, необходимо экспортировать данные из таблиц в xml файлы. Для этого решил использовать bcp. Экспортирую так:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(2000);
SET @cmd = 'bcp.exe "select * from tempxml.dbo.Normat AS Address FOR XML AUTO, ROOT(''Addresses'')" queryout C:\new\temp.xml -w -r -T';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Но возникают некоторые проблемы - во первых если выбрать ключ -c , то русский не отображается, если выбрать -w , то русский отображается, но размер файла увеличивается в два раза и кодировка UCS-2 Little Endian. Как можно сохранить это все в UTF-8? Вариант с открытием в другом редакторе и сменой кодировки не подходит. Во первых xml достаточно объемные, во вторых необходимо все делать в автоматическом режиме, например скрипт либо приложение на C#.

Вторая проблема это добавление спецификации вида (сейчас xml просто начинается с корневого тега):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Возможно есть другие методы экспорта данных в xml из ms sql 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то до MSSQL 2005 можно было делать так:

```
bcp.exe -c -C65001
```

Потом начиная с MSSQL 2008 эту возможность [убрали](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.110).aspx).

> SQL Server does not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding).